# Using Moq to see if method was called with a value

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing, moq

Using Microsoft Visual Studio 2017's built in test with Moq.

I have a simple class that creates some content, then sends the content to a notification system. I need to test if the notification system was called, but that the call included some text.

```
 public void DoStuff()
            var tenantSettings = _tenantService.GetTenantSettings();
            tenantSettings.Body = "xxx SOME VALUE xxx";
            MyService.SendMail(tenantSettings.Body);
```

How can I test that SendMail contains the text "SOME VALUE"?

I have a MOCK setup:

```
 MyServiceMock.Setup(x=>x.SendMail(It.IsAny<string>);
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can simply use `Verify` method on your mock:

```
MyServiceMock.Verify(x => x.SendMail("SOME VALUE"), Times.Once());
```

Edit:

If you want to verify whether the text passed as a parameter does not matches exactly, but just contains the tested value, you can use, as [Scott Chamberlain](https://stackoverflow.com/users/80274/scott-chamberlain) wrote:

```
MyServiceMock.Verify(x => x.SendMail(It.Is<string>(s => s.Contains("SOME VALUE")), Times.Once());
```

Comment: Note, this only matches the exact value `"SOME VALUE"` if the passed in string is `"xxx SOME VALUE xxx"` that will not match with this code.

Comment: That's true, I did not see the edit, the original question was different

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the `Verify` function allong with the `It.Is<TValue>(Func<TValue,bool>)` function to search for the substring.

```
MyServiceMock.Verify(x => x.SendMail(It.Is<string>(s => s.Contains("SOME VALUE")), Times.Once());
```

You put this line at the end of your test function after `DoStuff()` has been called.